# Can I change the font color and background color of a Spotfire cross table at the same time?

Tags: fonts, background-color, spotfire

I was able to change font color and background color one at time for a cross table. The requirement for the report is to have different condition in coloring the font and coloring the background.

[Cross Table Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQoui.png)
I can only set either font color or background color but not both at the same time. Is there a work around to get above results?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using only spotfire options. You have to chose between color or background color.

Here is a little trick to be able to do what you want, but note that this is not highly maintainable, and could stop working in future versions of Spotfire:

1. Set the color by on background color for what you need
2. Disable HTML sanitation if enabled (in Spotfire administrator options)
3. Add a textArea on your page (or use an existing one)
4. Add the following code (adapt it with your needs)

   ```
   $(".sfc-cross-table .sfc-value-cell div.cell-text").each( () => {
       if ( this.innerHTML == "OK" ) {
           this.style.color = "green";
       } else {
           this.style.color = "red";
       }
   });
   ```

I recommend you to post your idea on the [Spotfire ideas portal](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/introduction-tibco-ideas-portal) so that your feature could be taken into account for future spotfire versions.